# Nodejs - get value from database on application start for future use

Tags: sql, node.js, callback

I started with nodejs application which uses mssql database. For encryption/decryption purpose, I have encrypted key which is stored in database so everytime I encrypt/decrypt something, first I have to make call on database to get this value, decrypt it in callback of database call and then in another callback of decrypt function I use this value to pass it to encrypt function.

```
   sql.query("query to get key", [parameters],
            function (data) {
                if (data && (data.length == 1)) {       
                    Decrypt(data[0].Key, iv, salt, function (data) {
                        var decryptedKey = data;
                        Encrypt(inputData, decryptedKey, function (data){
                           var encryptedData = data;
```

What I want is to move "get key from database and decrypt it" logic on another place, actually to get it from database on application start and store it somewhere in variable to be available everywhere (decryptedKey ):

```
sql.query("query to get key", [parameters],
            function (data) {
                if (data && (data.length == 1)) {       
                    AESDecrypt(data[0].Key, iv, salt, function (data) {
                        var decryptedKey = data;
```

So, workflow should be:

- start nodejs application
- make this asynchronous call to database, get this key, decrypt it and store it in global variable
- use it in further calls to encrypt function

I already tried to move it in separate, helper file and just include this helper file in file where encryption/decryption logic is located, but word "**asynchronous**" is what makes confusions. It reads helper, does encryption/decryption but cannot be sure that this helper initialized and returned KEY value before encryption logic uses it, as it is asynchronous. 
So I get error messages in console about "unhandled promises, promise rejections" etc.

It does not ensure that decryptedKey gets initialized before Encrypt(inputData, decryptedKey) function uses it.

What can I do, is there something in nodejs like (in Angular, there is app.run()):

```
application.start() {
     // do some logic before all other actions
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a call function to application.listen() as second argument,which runs as soon as server starts.

```
application.listen(9090,function(){
  //do some logic before all other actions
});
```

Comment: You mean:

`application.listen(port,function(){
  sql.query("query to get key", [parameters],
            function (data) {
         .
         .
});`

where application is express instance?  

Ok, how can I store retrieved value on global level, to be available outside this listen function, to be available for helpers, routes and other files in project etc.

Comment: Why are you even storing the value in database if you need to retrieve it every time server starts? Why not keep it in some config file??

Comment: Because that's demand. To keep this key encrypted in database. Believe, I wished it to be stored in config too. As I mentioned in question, I have solution which retrieves from db and decrypts it on every encrypt/decrypt call, and it seems as bad practice as I now have "hell of callbacks". If I could do it only once on app start, I would get rid of these two callbacks regarding call on db and decryption of key.

Comment: setting a global variable from callback is not going to work.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. Made function in helper that accepts callback function as parameter, gets key from DB, decrypts it and passes it to callback function on success.

```
var decrypted = '';

var funcName= function (callback) {
   //get and decrypt key logic
   callback(data);
}
```

Then I invoked same function in that helper and passed it callback function which initializes my global variable "decrypted" with data:

```
funcName(function (data) {
   decrypted = data;
});
```

Then I have another function in helper which actually will be used wherever in app code, where encryption/decryption action is needed. It also takes callback as parameter:

```
getDecrypted: function (callback) {
    if (decrypted == '') {
        funcName(function (data) {
            decrypted = data;
            callback(decrypted);
        });
    }
    else {
        callback(decrypted);
    }
},
```

So, on app start, I will get my "decrypted" variable initialized with data, and wherever in app where I need it, I just include helper and use getDecrypted function, using my encryption or decryption function in its callback:

```
var helper = require('helper');

helper.getDecrypted(function (decrypted) {
      encryptLogic(input, decrypted, function (data) {
       .
       .
       .
```

So funcName will be invoked only once on app startup to initialize "decrypted" variable in helper.